# onmouseover change div text color

Tags: css, xhtml

On mouseover a div the background color is changing but not the div text color.

Can you please let me know if it is possible?

It's just a plain css and html.

my css code is

```
.divTable-row:hover{
            background:#65A3B8;
            color:#ffffff;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: seems to work fine for me (in all the latest browsers): http://jsfiddle.net/dSGf7/ do you have any overriding styles?

Comment: yes that's how it should work...let me check once again.

Comment: learnt new stuff...if the child div contains a color code then onmousover it's parent div won't change the text color...so I had to remove the child divs color and put it in parent div.Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force the style, with `!important` , like this:

```
    .divTable-row:hover{
        background:#65A3B8;
        color:#ffffff !important;
    }
```

this could fixed the issue when overlapping with another css rule.

Example fiddle with an overlapping problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dSGf7/2/

Fixed example using `!important` : http://jsfiddle.net/dSGf7/3/

Comment: learnt new stuff...if the child div contains a color code then onmousover it's parent div won't change the text color...so I had to remove the child divs color and put it in parent div.Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Thanks Nelson for this awesome example.

Comment: You really should avoid using `!important` unless absolutely necessary - see http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Thanks Andy for the link.It is really helpful.